# Latent Dirichlet Allocation and text Pre-Processing

Tags: text-mining, latent-variable

I think I understand the basic principles of LDA. However, browsing the githubs of people who applied this method, I noticed they pre-process the Corpus very specifically. For example, about the analysis of Sarah Palin email dataset, this guy ( ref: https://github.com/echen/sarah-palin-lda/blob/master/2-training.scala ) decided to:

- filter terms in < 10 docs
- filter out 30 most common terms
- take only docs with >= 10 terms

Obviously those filters change dramatically the results of the LDA.

My Question is : Which elements did he base on to decide to apply these filters?

Answer (score 2):

As always, it depends what do you want to get. In this particular case, just ask him.

Filtering out

- the most common terms (as usually they say little about particular *topics*, but are related to language) and
- the least common terms (so to avoid overfitting; think e.g. of a word used only once)

are a standard practice. Particular values are usually set by hand.